# On submitting a form, check for a value that, if present, opos up a modal window for more info

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, form-submit

I have a form that uses jQuery Validate. You click the Submit button, form gets validated and submitted via ajax. I want to add a step to this process.

I want to check for the presence of a value, say x. If x is NOT in the form I want to go ahead and submit it as I already do. If it IS in the form I want to open a modal window that requests further info THEN submits the form with that extra info added into the request.

Currently I can get the modal to trigger but then the form just continues with the submission. **How do I get the form submission to pause while the modal is dealt with by the user?**

jQuery Validate has a "success" option that is called after successful validation (which is when I want to check for triggering the modal) but that still doesn't pause execution.

**In a nutshell: How do I validate a submitted form, check if the value x is present, if it is not present submit the form but if it is present pause the submission, pop up a modal window, let the user fill in some more data (and presumably click a "done" or "cancel" button of some sort), add that to the collected form data and then submit the lot? The pausing submission part has me stumped.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `submit()` on the first form...

```
$('#form1').submit(function() {
    // The below validation goes in here
});
```

Validate it...

```
$("#form1").validate({
    // Whatever rules you want to validate by   
});
```

Check if the form is valid...

```
if($('#form1').valid()) {
    // Branching on x, example below, will go in here
} else {
    // It's not valid, stop the submission
    return false;
}
```

Branch on x. If present, open the modal, if not return true to submit the form as is

```
if (x !== undefined) {
    // Here is where you also need to pass the other form data to the modal
    // append hidden text fields to the form and populate with the values 
    // Open your modal window, then stop the default submit process
    $('#themodalwindow').openModal();
    return false;
} else {
    // No x so submit the form as is
    return true;
}
```

Now you have to submit the form in the modal...

```
$('#form2').submit(function() {
    return true;
});
```

If you appended the data collected in form1 to form2 then submitting the form will include everything you need. BTW, you can cache some stuff in that but this is the gist of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pause a form submit, but you can cancel it if you return false on the form's onsubmit event. After you get your additional data from the modal window, simply add the data to the form and resubmit it via javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Hook onto the form's submit function:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
   if (x !== undefined) {
       $('#dialog').show();
       return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: But after returning false how do I submit the form data combined with the extra data entered in the modal? Wouldn't I lose the form data after opening the modal and returning false?

Comment: You need to gather the data from the form and stick it in the form you are going to use in the modal (the "further info" you mention) or you will lose it, yes.

Comment: When they submit the information from the dialog box, you can hook onto the event and create a hidden hidden field on your form.  Give it an ID/Name and when the form submits, it will be serialized with the rest of the input elements.  Ideally, instead of checking for (x !== undefined), you should check for (x !== undefined && x.value !== ''), this way you can just populate that variable and resubmit the form instead of creating a new hidden field.